# Is Objective-C the only language with infix arguments?

Tags: language-design, objective-c

One of the things I like about Objective-C is the use of infix arguments when calling a method.

`[myDictionary setObject:myObject forKey:@"key"];`

where the method name is `setObject:forKey:`.

Does any other language do this?

Comment: Other languages tend to achieve this with named arguments, and typically make its use optional.

Comment: Ocaml has optional named arguments for functions.

Comment: Scala's infix mechanics are weird, but they let you do cool things. Haskell allows you to convert any 2 argument function into infix by calling it while it's surrounded in backticks. It also makes any purely symbolically-named function into infix automatically.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: The question is not about infix operators, it is about infix arguments, i.e. arguments which are interspersed in between the parts of the method name, e.g. for a method named `foo:bar:` it would be called `foo: 1 bar: 2` instead of `foo:bar:(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Objective-C inherited its core object-oriented features (minus categories and protocols), including the syntax, from [Smalltalk](http://Smalltalk.Org/), there's obviously at least Smalltalk that has the same syntax. Plus, all of the Smalltalk descendants such as [Self](http://SelfLanguage.Org/), [Newspeak](http://NewspeakLanguage.Org/) and [Fancy](http://Fancy-Lang.Org/).

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know Smalltalk was it's roots.

Comment: Objective-C is basically C + Smalltalk + types. Java is Objective-C - C, or, IOW, Smalltalk + types. ECMAScript is Scheme + NewtonScript (which is based on Self) with a little bit of Act-1 (which is based on Self). Ruby is Smalltalk + Perl. Smalltalk heritage runs deep in modern OO.